# Translating SHO from Matlab to C++

Tags: c++, matlab, translate

I´m trying to translate the Selfish Herd Optimization Algorithm from: https://la.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/64409-the-selfish-herd-optimizer-sho
for Ackley Function in dimension 10 and bounds (-32.768, 32.768).
But when I try to use the arrays for herd members and predators, I don't know how to access the rest elements of array A, the matlab code goes like this:
[Matlab Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51PRr.png)

My code goes like this:

```
int main1()
{
    //inicial values
    float min = -32.768;    //lower bound
    float max = 32.768;     //max bound
    const int dim = 10;     //dimension
    const int N = 50;
    //random a values
    float a[dim][N];
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            float random;
            random = (float)rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;
            a[i][j] = min + abs(max - min) * random;
        }
    }
    //Assing A members to H and P 
    float preys_rate[] = { 0.7,0.9 };
    float random = (float)0 + rand() % 1 / (float)RAND_MAX;
    float rate = preys_rate[0] + (preys_rate[1] - preys_rate[0]) * random;
    float N_h = round(N * rate);    //Herd members
    float N_p = N - N_h;            //Predator memebers
    //arrays
    float H[dim][35];
    float P[dim][15];
    //A to H
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N_h; j++)
        {
            H[i][j] = a[i][j];
        }
    }
    //Define the remaining "N_p" members in "A" as predator members
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 35; j < N; j++)
        {
            P[i][j] = a[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Could you help me with my code for assigning the rest of "a" elements to the array P?

Comment: please post minimal reproducible example ideally with comments in english

Comment: I'm sorry, if just updated my question

Comment: you can still water down your question and remove stuff I don't need to understand the problem you're facing. I had to read Matlab code just to understand what you mean. Not many people will spend time trying to understand the problem and will just ignore the question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you simply have a matrix `A` which you want to cut in 2 pieces horizontally into `H` and `P` matrices of sizes `N_h * dim` and `(N - N_h) * dim` respectively.

```
float H[N_h][dim];
float P[N - N_h][dim];

for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < dim; ++j) {
        if (i < N_h) 
            H[i][j] = a[i][j];
        else 
            P[i - N_h][j] = a[i][j];
    }
}
```

You can also optimize the code by hoisting the if condition outside the inner loop but any smart compiler would do it anyway.